# How to query on nested objects using GraphQL in EverShop

Tags: node.js, graphql, e-commerce

I was building an app with the Evershop Node E-commerce Platform. As per their documentation, I've added the GraphQL query for the product listing API to get the product list.

```
query GetAllProducts($filters: [FilterInput]) {
    products(filters: $filters) {
      items {
          name
          sku
          status
          image {
            alt
            thumb
            origin
          }
          price {
            regular {
              value
              text
            }
            special {
              value
              text
            }
          }
          weight {
            value
            unit
          }
      }

      total
      currentFilters{
        key
        value
      }
    }
  }
```

In this query, I've to pass the filter value to the variable `filters` like below:

```
const filters = [
    {
        key: "limit",
        operation: "eq",
        value: '10'
    }, 
    {
        key: "page",
        operation: "eq",
        value: '1'
    },
    {
        key: "name",
        operation: "ilike",
        value: '%jeans%'
    }
];
```

As you can see in my example, you can see that there is **price** field, which is defined as an object. How could I filter by product list based on the price field?

Answer (score 0):

To filter on specific fields within the price object, use dot notation to reach those fields directly.

For example, to filter products with a regular price greater than 50, you'd modify your filters array as follows:
JavaScript

```
const filters = [
    // ... other filters
    {
        key: "price.regular.value", // Access nested field using dot notation
        operation: "gt",       // Filter for values greater than
        value: '50'
    }
];
```

Comment: I've tried it before. But it doesn't work.

Comment: I also faced this issue, try to restart the system and get all the cache cleared from your end.
Try using Docker if possible. All such cache issues are avoided using the same.